# Redux function is only called after useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I want to check within useEffect when the status changes through redux whether a specific object is in the array. The problem is that useEffect is called BEFORE the decrement function within menuSlice is called. The whole thing should work the other way around.

```
const { menuState } = useSelector((state) => state.menu);

useEffect(() => {
const check = () => {
  const checking = menuState.filter((it) => it.title.title === item.title);

  if (checking.length > 0) {
    setAdded(true);
  } else {
    setAdded(false);
  }
};

menuState && check();
}, [menuState]);
```

IncrementDecrement.js

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const decrease = () => {
 dispatch(decrement(item));
};
```

menuSlice.js

```
const initialState = {
menuState: [],
};

export const menuSlice = createSlice({
name: "menu",
initialState,
reducers: {

increment: (state, action) => {
  state.menuState.push(action.payload);
},


decrement: (state, action) => {
  state.menuState.splice(
    state.menuState.findIndex((id) => id === action.payload),
    1
  );
  },
 },
});
```

Comment: When you change the state, the component subscribed to the state will be re-rendered, then you will get the latest value of the `menuState` in `useEffect`. Does this not work for you?